# Change mixins param inside another mixins

Tags: css, less, mixins

I have one mixins inside another mixins

```
 .background(@url:  @base-url , @repeat: repeat, @pos1: left, @pos2: center, @color: transparent){
     background:@arguments;
 }
```

Which is used in :

```
.divider{
    overflow:hidden;
    .background(@url: url("@{base-url}/divider.png") , @repeat: repeat-x, @pos2: bottom);
}

.class{
    .divider;

}
```

Is it possible to change only `@pos2` in `.divider` mixins?

Comment: It's not that evident what you mean with "Is it possible to change only `@pos2` in `.divider` mixins?" but probably [Named parameters](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-named-parameters) is what you need, e.g. `.background(@pos2: bottom);` (Assuming the question is something like "can I supply only `@pos2` arguments to the `.background` mixin and leave its other parameters in their defaults"). Otherwise it's probably what was suggested by @Xavier_Ex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can, add parameter to your `.divider` mixin and use that parameter as such:

```
.divider(@pos2: bottom) {
    overflow:hidden;
    .background(url("@{base-url}/divider.png"), repeat-x, @pos2);
}

.class{
    .divider(top); // you can use whatever value you want, or ignore it to use the default value 'bottom'
}
```